# Insert values from a json list of dicts containing the same keys for two different values in the list of dicts to a MYSQL database

Tags: python, mysql, json, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts stored in a json file1 with same keys but with two different values for each repeating key as shown below. I want to insert into a MySQL database where key matches a certain column then insert the two values into say column x and y after fetching the key from another json file2. This is because I a trying to update a table created to from json file 2 to contain additional values from the list of dicts from json file1

```
json file 1
[{"a": 0.022222222222162753,      
"b": 0.022222222222162753, 
"c":0.022222222222162753, 
"d": 0.022222222222162753,
"e": 2.6761620240410805e-12, 
"f": 0.022222222222162753},
{"a": 0.022222222222162753, 
"b": 0.022222222222162753, 
"c": 0.022222222222162753, 
"d": 0.022222222222162753, 
"e": 0.022222222222162753,
"f": 0.022222222222162753}]

json file 2
{"a":1,      
"b": 2, 
"c": 3, 
"d": 4,
"e": 5, 
"f": 6}
```

Here is my code for loading results into MySQL database according to a column that matches the repeating keys in the form, Key|value one| value two after finding the keys in another json file.

```
 for line3 in open("json file 2.json"):
    jline3=json.loads(line3)
    url3 =jline1["url"]

    for line4 in open("json file 1.json"):
        jline4 = json.load(line4)
        computedHITS=jline2[url3]

        """cursor.execute( """
          """  UPDATE `RANKED`.`EVALINDEX`
            SET `HITS`= %s
            WHERE `URL` = %s """
            """,  (computedHITS, url3))"""
        print "Number of rows inserted: %d" % cursor.rowcount
        db.commit() """
```

Comment: What solution do u have for dict?

Comment: Let me just add it now

Comment: Still its not clear what is not working? Please give problem statement where its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the whole files. Then loop json2 keys and do update if pk is in json1 file

```
>>> import json
>>> with open("file_2.json") as f2, open("file_1.json") as f1:
...     json_pks     = json.loads(f2.read())
...     json_updates = json.loads(f1.read())
...     for pk in json_pks:
...         x_value = json_updates[0].get(pk,'')
...         y_value = json_updates[1].get(pk,'')
...         
...         if x_value and y_value:
...             #db stuff
...             print "update YOUR_TABLE set x=%r,y=%r where YOUR_PK=%s" % (x_value,y_value,pk)
... 
update YOUR_TABLE set x=0.022222222222162753,y=0.022222222222162753 where YOUR_PK=a
update YOUR_TABLE set x=0.022222222222162753,y=0.022222222222162753 where YOUR_PK=c
update YOUR_TABLE set x=0.022222222222162753,y=0.022222222222162753 where YOUR_PK=b
update YOUR_TABLE set x=2.6761620240410805e-12,y=0.022222222222162753 where YOUR_PK=e
update YOUR_TABLE set x=0.022222222222162753,y=0.022222222222162753 where YOUR_PK=d
update YOUR_TABLE set x=0.022222222222162753,y=0.022222222222162753 where YOUR_PK=f
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write 2 loops in `json file1`

It must be like

```
for json_raw_data in open("json file 2.json"):
    # Load full json data at a time
    json_objects = json.loads(json_raw_data)
    #Loop over each dict in json data.
    for each_date in json_objects:
        #Do your operation
```